# Placement new and aligning for possible offset memory

Tags: c++, memory, placement-new

I've been reading up on `placement new`, and I'm not sure if I'm "getting" it fully or not when it comes to proper alignment.

I've written the following test program to attempt to allocate some memory to an aligned spot:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;
unsigned char* mem = nullptr;

struct A
{
  double d;
  char c[5];
};

struct B
{
    float f;
    int a;
    char c[2];
    double d;
};

void InitMemory()
{
    mem = new unsigned char[1024];
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    InitMemory();

    //512 byte blocks to write structs A and B to, purposefully misaligned
    unsigned char* memoryBlockForStructA = mem + 1;
    unsigned char* memoryBlockForStructB = mem + 512;

    unsigned char* firstAInMemory = (unsigned char*)(uintptr_t(memoryBlockForStructA) + uintptr_t(alignof(A) - 1) & ~uintptr_t(alignof(A) - 1));
    A* firstA = new(firstAInMemory) A();

    A* secondA = new(firstA + 1) A();
    A* thirdA = new(firstA + 2) A();

    cout << "Alignment of A Block: " << endl;
    cout << "Memory Start: " << (void*)&(*memoryBlockForStructA) << endl;
    cout << "Starting Address of firstA:  " << (void*)&(*firstA) << endl;
    cout << "Starting Address of secondA: " << (void*)&(*secondA) << endl;
    cout << "Starting Address of thirdA: " << (void*)&(*thirdA) << endl;
    cout << "Sizeof(A): " << sizeof(A) << endl << "Alignof(A): " << alignof(A) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Alignment of A Block: 
Memory Start: 0x563fe1239c21
Starting Address of firstA:  0x563fe1239c28
Starting Address of secondA: 0x563fe1239c38
Starting Address of thirdA: 0x563fe1239c48
Sizeof(A): 16
Alignof(A): 8
```

The output appears to be valid, but I still have some questions about it.
Some questions I have are:

- Will `fourthA`, `fifthA`, etc... all be aligned as well?
- Is there a simpler way of finding a properly aligned memory location?
- In the case of `struct B`, it is set up to not be memory friendly. Do I need to reconstruct it so that the largest members are at the top of the struct, and the smallest members are at the bottom? Or will the compiler automatically pad everything so that it's member `d` will not be malaligned?

Comment: You are probably looking for http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align

Comment: @DanM. Ahhh, that's great! I had no idea that existed. I could only find examples that assumed the buffer was going to be a homogenous type and recommended using alignas. I'll definitely look into this.

Comment: internal of B is correctly aligned thanks to padding (assuming B is constructed in aligned location). Rearrange order of member might make the class take less memory in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

> Will fourthA, fifthA, etc... all be aligned as well?

yes if the alignement of a type is a multiple of the size
witch is (i think) always the case

> Is there a simpler way of finding a properly aligned memory location?

yes

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas

or

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align
as Dan M said.

> In the case of struct B, it is set up to not be memory friendly. Do I need to reconstruct it so that the largest members are at the top of the struct, and the smallest members are at the bottom? Or will the compiler automatically pad everything so that it's member d will not be malaligned?

you should reorganize if you think about it.

i don't think compiler will reorganize element in a struct for you.
because often when interpreting raw data (coming from file, network ...) this data is often just interpreted as a struct and 2 compiler reorganizing differently could break code.

I hope my explanation are clear and that I did not make any mistakes